# Automate selecting multiple values

Tags: html, vbscript

I am trying to write a script that will select values on the webpage. Using the getElementByID("").value works when the element has one value. But there's another portion on the page where I want to select multiple.

The HTML is

```html
<select id = "locationID" multiple="multiple" value="3660">
```

When I manually select multiple values, the information in the value tag doesn't change. How would I write a selection for multiple values in vbs? This is the point of the automated process I'm trying to make, there are a lot of values on this list that I want to sift through a select.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give a try for this ***Multi_Select_ListBox.hta***

```
<HTML>
  <HEAD>
  <TITLE>Multi-Select</TITLE>
      <HTA:APPLICATION
      Application ID = "Multi-Select"
      APPLICATIONNAME = "Multi-Select"
      SYSMENU = "yes"
      WINDOWSTATE = "Normal"
      />
  </HEAD>
  <SCRIPT LANGUAGE="VBScript">
  '<!--#######################[ Multi-Select Listbox Menu ]#######################-->
      Sub RunMultiList
      Dim i,strChoices
          For i = 0 to (MultiListBox.Options.Length - 1)
              If (MultiListBox.Options(i).Selected) Then
                  strChoices = strChoices  & "Option " & MultiListBox.Options(i).Value & vbcrlf
              End If
          Next
          Msgbox "You Selected:" & vbcrlf & strChoices, 64,"Multi-Select ListBox Menu"
      End Sub 
  </script>
 <body>
  <!--==--==--==--==--==--==--==-- Multi-Select ListBox --==--==--==--==--==--==-->
  <CENTER>
  <FONT SIZE=3><B><I>Use Ctrl to Select Multiple Options:</I></B></FONT><BR><BR>
  <select size="8" name="MultiListBox" multiple>
  <option value="1">MultiListBox Option 1</option>
  <option value="2">MultiListBox Option 2</option>
  <option value="3">MultiListBox Option 3</option>
  <option value="4">MultiListBox Option 4</option>
  <option value="5">MultiListBox Option 5</option>
  <option value="6">MultiListBox Option 6</option>
  <option value="7">MultiListBox Option 7</option>
  <option value="8">MultiListBox Option 8</option>
  <option value="9">MultiListBox Option 9</option>
  <option value="10">MultiListBox Option 10</option>
  </select>
  <BR>
  <BR>
  <input type="button" onClick="RunMultiList" value="Submit">
  </CENTER>
  </BODY>
  </HTML>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, I was able to get it working using this code.